# Mongoose .findByIdAndDelete returning null

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

i have some issues with deleting objects in mongoose

I`ve been using mongoose version ^5.13.7 and .findByIdAndDelete request is giving me null, i have tried to use findByIdAndRemove and findOneAndDelete but it's not working either

Here is my deleting controller:

```
const deleteTour = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  const tour = await Tour.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id.trim());

  if (!tour) {
    return next(new AppError('No tour found with that ID', 404));
  }

  res.status(204).json({
    status: 'success',
    data: null,
  });
});
```

And here is the route where i`m using this controller:

```
const express = require('express');
const tourController = require('../controllers/tourController');
const authController = require('../controllers/authController');

const router = express.Router();

router
  .route('/top-5-cheap')
  .get(tourController.aliasTopTours, tourController.getAllTours);

router.route('/tour-stats').get(tourController.getTourStats);
router.route('/mouthly-plan/:year').get(tourController.getMouthlyPlan);

router
  .route('/')
  .get(authController.protect, tourController.getAllTours)
  .post(tourController.createTour);

router
  .route('/:id')
  .get(tourController.getTour)
  .patch(tourController.updateTour)
  .delete(
    authController.protect,
    authController.restrictTo('admin', 'lead-guide'),
    tourController.deleteTour
  );

module.exports = router;
```

The ID in request is correct
[console.log result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVroE.png)

Answer (score 0):

please check two things.

1. Is there any id in your req.params
2. Is there any data with that id in your db.

if the problem is not solved yet, please use `mongoose.Types.ObjectId` to validate your id.

Comment: id is correct, and object is in db with the same id

Comment: So use the mongoose.Types.ObjectId